# Fail to importing R libraries to Julia 1.4 using RCall

Tags: r, julia, rcall

Imported R libraries to julia using RCall (@rlibrary) cause "Segmentation Error" during run them (not at start the application). I am using latest version of both R (3.6.3) and Julia (1.4.1). Is there any solution?

Problem persists for any library, even R base.

Comment: are you using the 64-bit version of Julia?  (3.6.3 is no longer the latest R, as of a couple of days ago, but I doubt that matters)

Comment: Yes I am using 64-bit version.